# struts2 how to get the namespace value?

Tags: struts2

I have this secMarket.xml in my struts2 project, the code is below here:

```
<struts>
<package name="secMarket" namespace="/foliofn">
    <action name="loans" class="tlc.ui.action.Loans" >
        <result>/mainapp/pages/secMarket/loans.jsp</result>
    </action>   
</package>
```

how can I get the namespace value "/foliofn" as a String in the "execute" method of action class tlc.ui.action.Loans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  String namespace = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getNamespace();
```

Comment: you could also use ActionInvocation where necessary  

**`String namespace = invocation.getProxy().getNamespace();`**

Answer (score 0):

If i may ask why do you need the namespace ?
You can parse it from the request URI

Persumably your URI would look like this

http://{host:portno}/{applicationname}/foliofn/loans